# PInvoke CreateDesktop

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pinvoke

I am trying to PInvoke CreateDesktop in a way that passes the flag to inherit the desktop by child processes. The declaration is as follows:

```
[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "CreateDesktopW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateDesktop(string lpszDesktop, IntPtr lpszDevice, IntPtr pDevmode, int dwFlags,
                                                  int dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpsa);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int nLength;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public int bInheritHandle;
        }
```

And I use it as follows:

```
Win32.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new Win32.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            sa.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);
            sa.bInheritHandle = 1;
            testDesktopHandle = Win32.CreateDesktop(name, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0, Win32.GENERIC_ALL, sa);
```

And it unfortunately doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: Cannot marshal 'parameter #6': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (this value type must be paired with Struct).
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: it is always worth checking http://www.pinvoke.net/ for these type of problems.

Comment: Unless the reason you're here is because you got this exception from using a declaration you got from pinvoke.net... *(raises hand)*

Comment: @IanRingrose pinvoke.net declaration of `CreateDesktop` function is still bugged. It works only if one uses class to declare `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` and passes `null` as it's value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing parameter #6 to

```
static extern IntPtr CreateDesktop(..., [In] ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpsa);
```

*(This compiles and doesn't throw an exception at runtime, but I've tested it only with bogus arguments.)*

Compare with C++ declaration of [CreateDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682124(VS.85).aspx):

```
HDESK WINAPI CreateDesktop(..., __in_opt LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpsa);
                                  ↑      ↑ ↑
                                  [In] ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpsa
```

`LP` stands for "long pointer", i.e. `LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` is a pointer to a `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` struct. So in C# you need to pass your struct instance (value type) by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the following prototype instead:

```
    [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "CreateDesktopW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateDesktop(string lpszDesktop, IntPtr lpszDevice, IntPtr pDevmode, int dwFlags,
                                              int dwDesiredAccess, IntPtr lpsa);
```

Then to call it just create a pinned handle:

```
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(myStruct);
        try {
            IntPtr pinnedAddress = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        }
        finally {
            handle.Free();
        }
```

This works VERY well for calling PInvoke'd methods with structs.