# Managed application on secure desktop under Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, desktop-application, managed

I'm searching for the possibility to show an application on a secure desktop under Windows 7.
For explanation: The secure desktop is provided by Windows to avoid external applications to interact with this your application. It should be available to every application, as far as I know.
Commonly known examples are the UAC, the service user interaction desktop or the CardSpace-Application (integrated into Windows).
Actually it does not mean that every application on the secure desktop is automatically elevated ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715335/how-to-use-the-secure-desktop-in-windows-vista-and-w7)).

It do *not* want to show the UAC dialog together with my application, but *only* my application. It is a managed one, and I don't want to code any native code.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!
Greetings, relexx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emulate the "Secure Desktop" by calling CreateDesktop Win32 API, and you also can do this from C#, but I must warn you this is not for faint-hearted. A lot of perils awaits you on your way and it is not certain that you reach the desired destination successfully.

This link explains a bit how CreateDesktop works [CreateDesktop() with vista and UAC on (C, windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395351/createdesktop-with-vista-and-uac-on-c-windows), and this one shows how to call it from C# [PInvoke CreateDesktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434363/pinvoke-createdesktop).

You can also get some more information by googling CreateDesktop.

Good luck!